# Slack OAuth PHP - getting bot and webhook

Tags: php, oauth, slack-api, slack

I'm trying to use PHP to authenticate a user for a Slack integration. I've been able to receive a token and the basic user data using this:

https://github.com/adam-paterson/oauth2-slack

But it does not support the bot or web hook responses. How can I get this data?